# Why ng-scope is added to javascript inline of my partial view and makes alert not working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, partials, angularjs-view

I'm using AngularJs with templating system.
I want to add  specific inline javascript script to each template adding alert box regards to the selected tab ( Home | List | Settings )

**Html renders :** 
but ng-scope is added and nothing alerts when you change of tabs.

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="ng-scope">alert("home")</script>
```

I make the example available here :

http://bit.ly/HWcN1H

or here

[plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/BVZt3gdEQc4DhFoM6CUg?p=preview) with alert("template1") present into template1.html but renders as

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="ng-scope">alert("template1")</script>
```

Comment: Is that stray closing /script supposed to be there?

Comment: adding class to script tag, or any other tag won't stop script from running.... is there any text inside script tag? Wouldn't be surprised if it gets stripped out to avoid scripts over writing themselves. jQuery does same thing with their `html()` method, removes all scriot before DOM insertion

Comment: I may have the same issue, since my update to angular 1.2, my javascript code isn't loaded anymore with partials template.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have improved endorama's solution at  [github](https://gist.github.com/subudeepak/9617483#file-angular-loadscript-js)

The same process.

1. Create the angular-loadscript.js (from the link above)
2. in your app use 'ngLoadScript' as a resource dependency.

   var app = angular.module('YOUR_APP_NAME', ['ngResource','ngRoute', ...,'ngLoadScript']);
3. In your partial use 'text/javascript-lazy' as the MIME type.

Everything should work as required:

```
/*global angular */
(function (ng) {
  'use strict';

  var app = ng.module('ngLoadScript', []);

  app.directive('script', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) 
      {
        if (attr.type==='text/javascript-lazy') 
        {
          var s = document.createElement("script");
          s.type = "text/javascript";                
          var src = elem.attr('src');
          if(src!==undefined)
          {
              s.src = src;
          }
          else
          {
              var code = elem.text();
              s.text = code;
          }
          document.head.appendChild(s);
          elem.remove();
          /*var f = new Function(code);
          f();*/
        }
      }
    };
  });

}(angular));
```

Comment: I put multiple javascript lazies in the same file, and the load order doesn't jive =(

Comment: improved? copy-pasted you mean

Comment: How to make it synchronous call?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution by coding a directive :

https://gist.github.com/endorama/7369006

```
var app = ng.module('ngLoadScript', []);

  app.directive('script', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        if (attr.type=='text/javascript-lazy') {
          var code = elem.text();
          var f = new Function(code);
          f();
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

usage in partial :

```
  <script type="text/javascript-lazy" >
alert("lazy loaded");
  </script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this but still use the "src" attribute on the script tag?