# inline javascript within angular directive template url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dalliance

I'm trying to embed the [dalliance genome browser](http://www.biodalliance.org/embed.html) into an Angular application.
It works fine when placed on the main page.
However, because the app is large, I am trying to use a [Template-expanding directive](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/docs/guide/directive).
I read some posts about inline javascript not playing well along Angular, and the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917774/why-ng-scope-is-added-to-javascript-inline-of-my-partial-view-and-makes-alert-no/22476888#22476888). In particular I added this [gist](https://gist.github.com/subudeepak/9617483#file-angular-loadscript-js) to my app.

My app now looks like this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BvH6PM?p=preview).

**Question:** The genome browser plugin does **not** appear :-( What's wrong?

**app.js:**

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
        .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.title = "Genome Browser";
        }])
        .directive('genomeBrowser', function() {
            return {
                templateUrl: 'genomeBrowser.html'
            };
        });
})(window.angular);
```

**genomeBrowser.html:**

```
<h2>Embedded page:</h2>
<script type='text/javascript-lazy' language="javascript">
    new Browser(options);
</script>
<div id="svgHolder"></div>
```

(The `options` are not relevant here but can be seen in the plunker.)

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Genome browser</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-loadscript.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.biodalliance.org/release-0.13/dalliance-compiled.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="docsTemplateUrlDirective">
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <div genome-browser></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include 'ngLoadScript' as a dependency:

```
angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
```

should be

```
angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', ['ngLoadScript'])
```

Also, there was a missing quote in your partial in `console.log('debug');`

Comment: Nice catch! I'll accept yours since it answers the question, but work with the other answer where the code is moved into the directive.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I moved all inline javascript into the directive.

**app.js:**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app', []);

    angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.title = "Genome Browser";
    }]);

    angular.module('app').directive('genomeBrowser', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'genomeBrowser.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: function($scope) {
                var browser = new Browser({
                    pageName: 'dalliance', // Target element ID.

                    chr: '22',
                    viewStart: 30000000,
                    viewEnd: 30030000,
                    cookieKey: 'human',

                    coordSystem: {
                        speciesName: 'Human',
                        taxon: 9606,
                        auth: 'NCBI',
                        version: '36',
                        ucscName: 'hg18'
                    },

                    sources: [{
                        name: 'Genome',
                        uri: 'http://www.derkholm.net:8080/das/hg18comp/',
                        tier_type: 'sequence',
                        provides_entrypoints: true
                    }, {
                        name: 'Genes',
                        desc: 'Gene structures from Ensembl 54',
                        uri: 'http://www.derkholm.net:8080/das/hsa_54_36p/',
                        collapseSuperGroups: true,
                        provides_karyotype: true,
                        provides_search: true
                    }, {
                        name: 'Repeats',
                        uri: 'http://www.derkholm.net:8080/das/hsa_54_36p/',
                        stylesheet_uri: 'http://www.derkholm.net/dalliance-test/stylesheets/ens-repeats.xml'
                    }, {
                        name: 'MeDIP raw',
                        uri: 'http://www.derkholm.net:8080/das/medipseq_reads'
                    }, {
                        name: 'MeDIP-seq',
                        uri: 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/das-srv/genomicdas/das/batman_seq_SP/'
                    }]
                });
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

**genomeBrowser.html:**

```
<div id="dalliance"></div>
```

I still have things to learn about how to properly *control* this browser my for next homework, but this answers the question.

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/KSUVq8?p=preview